# How Can I Ensure Fonts on Vercel Deployment Match Those on Localhost in a Next.js with Shadcn UI Project?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, vercel, shadcnui

Has anyone else experienced discrepancies in fonts between their local development environment and their Vercel deployment in Next.js projects, particularly when using Shadcn UI? Despite having identical font configurations, the deployed version's fonts appear differently than on localhost. What steps can be taken to resolve this issue and achieve font consistency across development and production environments?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact issue in my Next.js project utilizing Shadcn UI, where the fonts on my Vercel deployment did not match those on my localhost. After some investigation, I discovered a solution that effectively ensured font consistency across my development and production environments.

The issue seems to stem from how Vercel's build cache handles font files, potentially leading to discrepancies when fonts are updated or changed. The solution is to force a fresh build without using the cache. Here's how:

1. Navigate to your project's dashboard on Vercel.
2. Go to the "Deployments" section.
3. Click on the "Redeploy" button for your latest deployment.
4. Importantly, choose to redeploy without using the build cache.

This process forces Vercel to rebuild your project from scratch, ensuring that all font configurations are correctly applied and reflected in the deployment, just as they are on localhost.

By sharing this, I hope to help others facing similar font inconsistency issues in their Next.js projects on Vercel. This approach worked for me, and I believe it's a valuable workaround for anyone encountering the same problem.